# Checks of the owner and the existence of the resource in the middleware to avoid repeating itself in the controller?

Tags: php, slim

In my Slim 4 API, I have a group of routes which manages *vehicles* (= resource). Overall they look like this:

- **GET /api/v1/vehicles/{id}**
- **PUT /api/v1/vehicles/{id}**
- **DELETE /api/v1/vehicles/{id}**

They call respectively the `get()`, `update()`, `delete()` methods in the `VehicleController` class.
As these are resources protected by an API authentication, in each method, I have the same code which is repeated at the beginning:

- Check that the vehicle with the id exists in the database (yes = continue, no = return a 404 error)
- Check that the vehicle with the id belongs to the authenticated person (yes = continue, no = return a 403 error)

Instead of repeating the code each time, is it correct to create a middleware with these two checks and attach it to the route group that manages the vehicles?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Not sure if the term *is it correct* is in itself correct.  You can code it however you want, but a middleware check could be a good method of doing this as it can stop the process as soon as it decides that the process is not valid.

Comment: The middleware is only responsible for request & response specific tasks, but not for the core business logic. I would add a Domain layer with Service classes to manage this kind of business logic.